# Pip install results in error "no such option: -E"

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

I just cleaned up my mac after a mavericks install (yeah, i'm late to the party).
I'm using homebrew Python but I've confirmed this error with the stock apple python as well.  I've got pip 1.5.6 installed system-wide and also in my virtualenv.

I can pip-sys install for system-wide pip installs no problem.  When In a virtualenv though, I get the following error, even with `which pip`.

```
pip install -U -r requirements/dev.pip

Usage:   
  pip <command> [options]

no such option: -E
```

Comment: Can you include your requirements file(s) or just check if any lines of it include the -E option?

Comment: Yes, there are lines that include `-e` but not `-E`.  I think `-E` is a sudo thing.  If I sudo the install it gets past this error but fails in other places unrelated to pip.  I should not have to sudo an install on a virtualenv.  Also, I tried removing the `-e` from the requirements file and that didn't change this error.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is something wrong with the pip install within the virtualenv.  Pip is not working but pip2 install works fine.  So maybe there's a version conflict where pip installs thinking it's a different python version from what was installed.

To recap

```
pip install south
```

fails with above error

```
pip2 install south
```

works fine.